# How to chain with clauses in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've a User model which have many Orders (Order model), and each Order belongs to a Translator (Translator Model).

The behavior that I'm trying to reach is when I fetch a User by his Id, I want to get his orders and the translator associated with each order.

I try to use this code: `$user = User::where('id', $id->id)->with('orders')->with('translator')->get();`, I expect that it will return the proper data which should be something like this:

```
{
   ...user data,
   orders: [
       {
           ...order_data,
           translator: {
              ...translator_data
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

but that doesn't work.
Is there anyway to get this behavior in Laravel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eager load nested relationships using the `.` to distinguish this:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id->id)->with('orders.translator')->first();
// or
$user = User::with('orders.translator')->find($id->id);
```

Side Note, if `$id` is a User instance you can Lazy Eager Load the relationship on it:

```
$id->load('orders.translator');
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading - Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `with`

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading - Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) `load`